# Translation of the German “Gesetz entschärfen”

Tags: phrase-requests, translation, german

I am trying to translate the sentence

> Da die USA ihre Gesetze bezüglich Marihuana **entschärft haben**, wurde auch in Deutschland eine Debatte angestoßen.

and arrived at:

> Since the USA **[verb]ed** their legislation regarding marijuana, a debate in Germany was initiated.

*Entschärfen* in this context means to change the laws such that they are less strict and prohibit less.

Translating *entschärfen* directy gives me *to defuse,* but that doesn’t sound right in this context. 
Linguee offers me no translation for the phrase *Gesetz entschärfen.*

What would be the correct translation of this phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The US **softened** the legislation...

[Example 1:](http://www.nola.com/crime/index.ssf/2016/06/new_orleans_softer_marijuana_p.html)

> New Orleans softens marijuana possession laws starting this week

[Example 2:](http://www.takepart.com/article/2015/05/26/louisiana-marijuana-reform)

> This Southern State May Soften Its Marijuana Laws

Answer (score 2):

*Relaxed* is my go-to here. And then the opposite is to *tighten* a rule or regulation.

> (intransitive, of codes and regulations) To become more lenient.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/relax#English)

> to make a rule or control less severe:
>
> *Two weeks after the police relaxed security at the airports, there was a bomb attack.*

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/relax)

Usage example (UK Government source):

> Starting in May 2020, the laws were slowly relaxed.

[Coronavirus: A history of English lockdown laws](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-9068/)